# could not use "cv2.imshow('Lena', img)" in jupyter notebook

Tags: opencv, opencv3.3

It gives this error:

`error Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5e400e6b9939> in <module>()
      1 img = cv2.imread(imgpath)
      2 
----> 3 cv2.namedWindow('Lena', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
      4 cv2.imshow('Lena', img)
      5 cv2.waitKey(0)
error: /tmp/build/80754af9/opencv_1512687413662/work/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:593: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow`

I installed this package using conda so unable to understand how to make changes in that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with your opencv, from the error my assumption is you built it from source.
l would advise uninstalling the current opencv you have and install via pip `pip install opencv-python`